# How can I make character movement in 2d game with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't make the image with id yoshi move around my 2d game

```js
document.onkeydown = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) yoshi.style.left = yoshi.offsetLeft - 5 + "px";
  else if (e.keyCode == 38) yoshi.style.top = yoshi.offsetTop - 5 + "px";
  else if (e.keyCode == 39) yoshi.style.left = yoshi.offsetLeft + 5 + "px";
  else if (e.keyCode == 40) yoshi.style.top = yoshi.offsetTop + 5 + "px";
};
```

```css
#yoshi {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="quarto">
    <img src="assents/image/yoshi.png" alt="yoshi" id="yoshi" />
  </div>
</body>
```

The right and down movement is normal, but when I press the up and left keys, yoshi keeps walking down and right, respectively

Answer (score 2):

Mixing `style` and `offsetTop`/`offsetLeft` is difficult. Use `getComputedStyle` if you don't want to set the initial values of `top` and `left` in HTML (inline CSS). If you don't mind inline CSS, replace `getComputedStyle(yoshi)` with `yoshi.style`.

```js
document.onkeydown = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) yoshi.style.left = parseInt(getComputedStyle(yoshi).left) - 5 + "px";
  else if (e.keyCode == 38) yoshi.style.top = parseInt(getComputedStyle(yoshi).top) - 5 + "px";
  else if (e.keyCode == 39) yoshi.style.left = parseInt(getComputedStyle(yoshi).left) + 5 + "px";
  else if (e.keyCode == 40) yoshi.style.top = parseInt(getComputedStyle(yoshi).top) + 5 + "px";
};
```

```css
#yoshi {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="quarto">
    <img src="assents/image/yoshi.png" alt="yoshi" id="yoshi" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the good answer by @haolt:

Don't rely on the styles to store the position. Instead store the position yourself. For example:

```
const yoshiPosition = {top: 0, left: 0};

document.onkeydown = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) yoshiPosition.left += 5;
  else if (e.keyCode == 38) yoshiPosition.top -= 5;
  else if (e.keyCode == 39) yoshiPosition.left -= 5;
  else if (e.keyCode == 40) yoshiPosition.top += 5;

  yoshi.style.top = yoshiPosition.top + "px";
  yoshi.style.left = yoshiPosition.left + "px";
};
```